# ajax call having slashes in the request params gives not found error

Tags: ajax

i want to send String dates to the **RestController** using ajax

as follows

```
 $(document).on("click","#holidaySubmit",function(event){    

     var holidays=$('#holiday').val();  //11/07/2018,14/07/2018,20/07/2018,18/07/2018,24/07/2018 

     var url = contextPath+"/master/generateWrkDaysOfMonthBasedOnHolidays/"+holidays;       
        $.ajax({          
            url : url,         
            type:"post",    
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',  
            async: false,         
            success:function(response) 
            {    
                console.log(response);
            }
         });
 });
```

**post method**

```
@PostMapping("/generateWrkDaysOfMonthBasedOnHolidays/{holidays}")
                        public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> generateWrkDaysOfMonthBasedOnHolidays(@PathVariable("holidays") String holidays) {
            //to do         
}
```

when i submit the request to controller , i am getting following error in console

```
http://localhost:8026/campasAdmin/master/generateWrkDaysOfMonthBasedOnHolidays/11/07/2018,14/07/2018,20/07/2018,18/07/2018,24/07/2018 404 (Not Found)
```

i think this is because of **/** in the String .

how to solve this please help me.
thank you !.

Comment: pass the date as `json` not query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you @ Elyas Esna  based  on your suggestion, ajax call must be

```
$(document).on("click","#holidaySubmit",function(event){     

     var holidays=$('#holiday').val();

     var days=holidays.split(",");
     var myJSON = JSON.stringify(days);
     var url = contextPath+"/master/generateWrkDaysOfMonthBasedOnHolidays";       
        $.ajax({          
            url : url,         
            type:"post",
            data : myJSON,
            contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8',  
            async: false,         
            success:function(response) 
            {    
                console.log(response);
            }
         });
 });
```

thank you.